# add multiple menus to push down content

Tags: jquery

i have a single link when clicked reveals a div and pushes down content

i would like to add additional  links that reveal their own divs beneath

the following jquery code only works if I'm using 1 link, how do i have additional links that reveal their own div's?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var menu = $('#menu')
$('#menu-trigger').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if (menu.is(":visible"))
{
      menu.slideUp(400);
      $(this).removeClass("open");
}
else
{
      menu.slideDown(400);
      $(this).addClass("open");
}
}); 

});
```

Comment: there are lots and lots of resources on web how to create a menu. Study some tutorials , or use a plugin. Either way you are basically asking for someone to take an overly simplistic start point and create a more complex widget for you

Comment: I'm not trying to create a menu or a widget, the foundation is already there, i just want some guidance on how i can add additional parameters to the existing code

Comment: the point is you don't have a good foundation to start with and therefore should do some research

Comment: I do believe i have a good foundation, since the html and css are present and working perfectly well. The jquery in question also works perfectly well. I was simply asking for someone to enlighten me on how i would repeat the process if i was to add an additional link to reveal refresh content, without clashing with the existing link.

Comment: and there are lots and lots of tutorials and websites and open source scripts devoted to helping you figure it out. Your question is too broad for this site as it stands

Comment: Much more vague questions have been answered here, i have learned more from this site due to the transparency of information and the problem solving process with trial and error, than a one dimensional tutorial.

Comment: this has been solved by "superUntitled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a class to bind the click and a data-attribute to find the id of the drawer, that way you can write the toggle once, and reuse it on many elements.

```js
    $('.toggler').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var menu = $(this).data('menu');
      $("#"+menu).slideToggle(400);
      $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
```

```css
.drawer { display:none; }
.open { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"  class='toggler'  data-menu="foo">click</a>
    <a href="#" class='toggler' data-menu="bar">click</a>
    <div id="foo" class="drawer">stuff</div>
    <div id="bar" class="drawer">other stuff</div>
```

Comment: thanks superUntitled - works perfectly